# I want to sync user contacts to firebase firestore in one go

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat, querying

I am building chat application somewhat like whatsapp. I want to show registered app users list from user's device contact list while creating new group. Now in order to do that I have to compare each and every contact number with firebase firestore users. And any normal user can have more than 500 contacts in device. And moreover firestore has limitation to for querying the db so I can not compare more than one number at a time, the whole process takes almost 6-7 minutes as well as each read operation costs financially.

How can I overcome with this situation, or what is the better way to deal with this particular scenario?

Comment: I just tested this with a quick Firebase app (not Firestore) and I can query for 500 phone numbers in about 2 seconds (Swift 4) and store the matching ones in an array. Not sure what's causing your delay but it's not Firestore as the performance is not far off from Firebase.

Comment: With further testing, assuming that you find a match for every contact (500 of them) that increases the time to 8 seconds, including printing to the console. Now, that's using a query. If you create a node that stores only phone numbers then you can avoid the query completely and just check to see if the node exists. In that case, it's so fast it not even worth measuring.

Comment: @Jay I don't know time consumption with realtime db, but I am using react native and firestore for sure taking that much time.

Comment: @Jay ok I have also tried with realtime db and it goes down to 4 minutes but yours are 4 seconds.. can I have your db structure and swift code how you do query.

Comment: @Jay can you share you schema please?

Comment: @SagarKhatri can you share your final solution?

Comment: @Ran we dropped the whole syncing feature. What I think is you need a server to execute such process. Else there will be a lot of read/write/update and you end up paying a lot more to firebase.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the contacts of the user on device and only send them to firestore as backup. You can then sync your local database with firestore on app start. 
The operations you need are not possible to be robust in firebase. Even then if you want to do a search in firebase data, you need to use 3rd party search solution like Elastic Search with your firebase data to perform complex searching.

For local database you can use Room library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

For using Elastic Search with Firebase have a look at this utility Flashlight: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flashlight .

Comment: I don't need any complex searching or even text search. it's a precise text compare e.g. `device.phoneNumber == firestore.phoneNumber` but the thing is I have 500+ contacts and it's time taking, and I am syncing the contacts while app starts but what if user just closes the app in a minute or so. syncing takes more than 6 minutes right now

Comment: you can make sync efficient by using child event listener and keep storing the data in local database, next time when app start get the last record stored locally, get its id set your query to read from that point. this will work since the ids generated by firebase are sorted so you will not miss any.

Comment: that can help me for syncing but I want to optimize this and want to run this operation in seconds..

Comment: index your data in local database for phone numbers and your search will speedup significantly. Also if you index firebase database and query directly that will improve your search in firebase as well.

Comment: firestore autoindex your document key so that's not an issue and I store the device contacts on my app so that is also not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The OP requested a structure and some code (Swift, Firebase Database) as a solution. I will present two options

If you want to use a Firebase Query to see if the phone numbers exist, a possible stucture would be

```
users
  uid_0
    contact_name: "Larry"
    contact_phone: "111-222-3333"
  uid_1
    contact_name: "Joe"
    contact_phone: "444-555-6666"
```

and then the swift code to query for existing numbers

```
let phoneNumbers = ["111-222-3333","444-555-6666"] //an array of numbers to look for
let myQueryRef = self.ref.child("users")
for contactPhone in phoneNumbers {
    let queryRef = myQueryRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "contact_phone").queryEqual(toValue: contactPhone)
    queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("found \(contactPhone)") //or add to array etc
        }
    })
}
```

Having queries in a tight loop like this is generally not recommended but it usually works fine for me with low iterations. However, queries have a lot more overhead than .observers.

IMO, a better and considerably faster option is to keep a node of just phone numbers. Then iterate over the ones you are looking for and use .observe to see if that node exists.

```
phone_numbers
   111-222-3333: true
   444-555-6666: true
```

and then the code to see if the ones from the array exist

```
let phoneNumbers = ["111-222-3333","444-555-6666"] //an array of numbers to look for
let phoneNumberRef = self.ref.child("phone_numbers")
for contactPhone in phoneNumbers {
    let ref = phoneNumberRef.child(contactPhone)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("found \(contactPhone)")
        }
    })
}
```

In testing, this second solution is must faster than the first solution.